# rotating servos by pressing keyboard using arduino , johhny five or java script?

Tags: javascript, keyboard, arduino

like when i press a specific key one of the servo rotate right as long
as i hold that key, and so on for a total of four servos and each to
have its specific keyboard key ,

> example ( for servo 1 pressing "a" for left, "b" for right. for servo
>   2 "z"for left,"c" for right) i want to make it keyboard control.

i don't know the code to make the 4servos controlled by keyboard.. i
think i have to use firmata on arduino and the code written in
javascript ? its ok also or another method. thanks in advance

Comment: You could take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10868718/control-servo-with-keyboard-or-other-hardware-buttons

Comment: In one way you can use Ethernet at Arduino and js at web.

Answer (score 0):

For sending data between Arduino and my computer I use processing, a fairly simple programming language similar to JavaScript. Using processing, you could establish a serial connection with the Arduino and send data back and forth. In your case, your processing code would get keyboard events and then send that data through usb to the Arduino. Here is a good tutorial: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/connecting-arduino-to-processing. If you need any further help, just ask.

Example Arduino Code:

```
char c = '.';

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(100);                   // Power up delay
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
     c = Serial.read();
  }
  if(c == '.'){
    //no key pressed
  }
  if(c == 'a'){
    //a key pressed
  }
}
```

Example Processing Code:

```
import processing.serial.*;

Serial myPort;
char valToWrite = '.';

void setup() {
  smooth();
  size(300, 350);

  //Might need to change number in bracket based on the serial port your arduino is connected to
  String portName = Serial.list()[3];
  println(portName);
  myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 9600);
  myPort.bufferUntil('\n');
}

void draw() {
  //Draw Something here, if you want visual representation
}

void keyPressed(){
  valToWrite = key;
  myPort.write(valToWrite);
}

void keyReleased(){
  valToWrite = '.';
  myPort.write(valToWrite);
}
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: thanks. yah processing seems good way actually.. i tried the examples in the link it worked and i got to know it.i also tried to run my (hitec) servos it worked so i have no issues with them. but i dont know what codes to use ! i mean lets assume that the servos are on pin (3,6,9,10)on arduino and everything is set. just the processing code and arduino code left.. i dont know the servo codes or keyboard pressing codes.

Comment: if u could write  a simple code for the servos. and put any keyboard key (a,b,c etc) to rotate the servo to left or right as long as im pressing that keyboard key.. just so i see how the arduino and processing codes codes are.. id really appreciate it